# Parsing String to Date object changed value

Tags: java, datetime

To change the time format (from `HH:mm:ss` to `HH:mm`), I used the following snippet.

```
Date dateObj = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String time = simpleDateFormat.format(dateObj);
```

When I test with the correct time, it can change the format correctly.
But, when I test with wrong time, it change not only format but also time itself.
For example,

- `1:70:00` => `02:10` (after converting)
- `27:00:00` => `03:00` (after converting)

I only would like to change the format instead of changing both format and value.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What should be the result if your time is `27:00:00`. That makes no sence.

Comment: Can't you use a substring to remove seconds??

Comment: Try with `setLenient(false)` to date format, otherwise the time values are not checked whether match to individual formats or not.

Comment: It converting fine because 1:70:00= 2:10,means 70 minute = 60 minute + 10 minute . Date parse function will convert 60 minute in 1 hour and add in last 1 hour now it will be 1+1=2 and remain 10 will be count as minute thats why it is giving output 02:10.same condition apply on second .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse a time string like "1:70", Java calculates the canonical time from that as "2:10".
Since you don't want such time recalculation, simply reformat with:

- drop seconds
- add padding zeros

It's better to use String operations. For example something like this:

```
    String str = "1:70:00";
    String[] parts = str.split(":");
    String newFormat = String.format("%02d:%02d", Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    // will be: "01:70"
```

Comment: Not only I want to remove the seconds but also I want to format time as "HH:mm". So, I would like to know whether I can do such thing without using substring. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I also wrote my own formatter same as yours. Currently, I solved the problem by using that.

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect when converting 1:70:00 to a Date object? The Date can hold only valid values and 1:70:00 is not valid.

This is the expected. If you need something different behavior then you should write your own formatter which converts a String to a String.

Comment: In fact, I've written my own formatter. What I would like to know is whether I can convert such thing without own formatter. I would like to get "01:70" when converting "1:70:00" to Date object. After parsing "1:70:00", the value become "02:10". This may be because "Date can hold only valid values" as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Locale;
import org.joda.time.MutablePeriod;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodParser;

public class APP3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
        builder.printZeroAlways()
                .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
                .appendHours()
                .appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes();

        PeriodFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();
        PeriodParser parser = builder.toParser();

        String time = "27:70:00";
        MutablePeriod mp = new MutablePeriod();
        parser.parseInto(mp, time, 0, Locale.getDefault());

        System.out.println("Case 1 : "+formatter.print(mp));

        int hours = mp.getMinutes()/ 60;
        int minutes = mp.getMinutes() % 60;
        mp.setHours(mp.getHours()+hours);
        mp.setMinutes(minutes);

        System.out.println("Case 2 : "+formatter.print(mp));

    }
}
```

Output

```
run:
Case 1 : 27:70
Case 2 : 28:10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

and import lib :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

ref :[joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) http://joda-time.sourceforge.net

Comment: I don't use `joda-time` because I don't like to import another lib. Anyway, thanks.